# Can't compile with ocaml (ocamlopt) and float

Tags: ocaml

I have a problem compiling with ocamlopt and floats

I'm under Ubuntu 10.04 and Ocaml 3.11

for this line :

```
let a = 10.0;;
```

no worries with top level

no worries with ocamlc (code in a test.ml file) :

```
ocamlc -o exec test.ml
```

error with ocamlopt :

```
ocamlopt -o exec test.ml
```

message :

> File "test.ml", line 1, characters 0-1:
>   Error: Assembler error, input left in file /tmp/camlasm5c3d4d.s

Where is this coming from ?

**EDIT : Problem solved, the 3.12 fixes the [bug](http://caml.inria.fr/mantis/view.php?id=5237)**

Thank you guys :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like a [known issue](http://caml.inria.fr/mantis/view.php?id=5237), and the bug only appears with a specific combination of binutils and ocaml that should not appear with official packages from Ubuntu 10.04. Are you using only official packages? If so, could you provide your exact versions of binutils and ocaml?

There is a patch for ocaml in aforementioned bugreport, but the easier fix is to upgrade if you can. If you are using only official packages, a bugreport should be submitted to Ubuntu so that the package is fixed.

Comment: indeed, updating Ocaml installation solved the bug, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

The OCaml native compiler works by generating assembly code and calling the system's assembler to assemble it.  Your compiler appears to be generating assembly code that's not acceptable to the assembler.  As nlucaroni says, this is some kind of version mismatch.  The OCaml compiler is (essentially) expecting a different assembler than it's getting.

If you show the output from nlucaroni's suggested options, it might give a hint of what's going wrong.  It might also be interesting to look at `/tmp/camlasm5c3d4d.s`, the assembly file generated by the compiler.

It also might be interesting to see the output of

```
ocamlopt -config
```

This will show what assembler it's trying to run, and other useful info.

Unfortunately, I don't believe the assembler is configurable from the command line of ocamlopt.  I have actually fixed this problem in the past by creating a script that pretends to be the assembler (to specify extra flags to the real assembler).  If you're not up for hacking around like this, you might have to ask for help from whoever packaged up your OCaml.

Answer (score 3):

I had no problem compiling that line with/ OCaml 3.11.1, 3.12.0, 3.12.1, and OCaml 3.13.0+dev8. Add the following to the ocamlopt compile line to see where the problem is really happening,

```
-verbose -ccopt -v -cclib -v
```

You'll be able to see the lines that ocamlopt are throwing to external programs and in turn how they execute the command.This is probably an issue with `gcc`; multiple version conflict? In which case you'll have to recompile OCaml. I recall `gcc` and the linux kernel had major version updates in Ubuntu 11.04, you might be experiencing something similar. There should be other versions of `gcc` on the system, try `gcc-4.4`. Are you using the OCaml supplied package or did you compile yourself?

Comment: I have gcc 4.5 but your options don't give me any hint about version conflicts; And OCaml was in a package, indeed

Comment: The options I suggested wouldn't directly give you version mismatch information. They would just show you what phase in the compilation is truly the error. Did you install GCC through the pkg manager as well?Also, check your PATHS that the OCaml you are using is the one installed from the package manager. I really think this due to the kernel upgrade. I know I had major issues with the native compilation when I upgraded back in June. When did you upgrade? Or is this a fresh install?

Comment: You know what. I was thinking 11.04 had major changes, not 10.04. Shouldn't I realize what year it _just_ was?? you'd think. That doesn't change the conclusions I have on your problem.